# Using SkyEpub jar library in an android project

Tags: android, epub, epub3

I am going to use [SkyEpub 3](http://skyepub.net/)  library in my android application to read ebooks in epub format. To get familiar with the method of using SkyEpub I have downloaded its android demo project from [here](http://www.skytree21.com/cgi-bin/download.php?os=android&version=3.9.8&type=core_sample).
Its demo project is working properly, But when I use the skyepub.jar in my own project, it says some methods and classes from the jar file are undefined. Of course in the mean time I am using an unlicensed version of this library. I want to test it before buying the license if it was ok. I doubt that the errors are because of using the unlicensed version of the library in my project.
Can any one tell me please what is the problem exactly?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was the problem. I increased priority of the jar file in eclipse. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Because there are a lot of classes ,which are not in jar, in example project. In the example, they create a lot of classes by extends another classes from jar. I used this jar before.

Comment: I know but the classes like BookInformation which is defined in the jar file are becoming undefined when i use skyepub.jar in my project. But they are all known in the demo project.

Comment: @m.taheri I think, firstly you should check your imports. Are you importing from jar or somewhere else. Remove all imports and then import them again for double check. I'm assuming you configured build path.

Comment: All imports are correct. I am stuck with this problem.